# How to handle many ImageViews in Android without having memory issues?

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, android-imageview

I am trying to develop a simple card game in Android Studio, played by four players. I am struggling at the very beginning though. I am new at android programming, but not in Java developing.

I just want to do the card distribution (card dealing), that will split the 52 cards to each player, located in WEST, SOUTH, EAST, NORTH in the screen.

So I guessed, I will need 52 ImageViews representing cards, so I created a class:

```
public class Card extends ImageView {
  public Card(Context context, int id) {
    super(context);
    setImageResource(id);
  }
}
```

I have a static array of strings with 52 elements representing card names, a hashtable that has for key the card name and for value a Card object, and I have the images of all the cards in the drawable folder, named the same as they are named in the static array, so I can map them.
I am trying to do this in the MainActivity:

```
for (String cardName : cardNames) {
  int imageId = Utilities.getResId(cardName, R.drawable.class);//this just 
  //gets the id of the image in R
  Card card = new Card(this, imageId);
  cards.put(cardName, card);
  linearLayout.add(card);
}
```

I also set the linearLayout I populate above in the content view, by calling the method:

```
setContentView(linearLayout);
```

The error I am getting is

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 11675148 byte allocation with 10183056 free bytes and 9MB until OOM.
```

This error is thrown in the for loop at about the 15th loop.

Now this surely feels like the wrong way to handle this problem. What is the best approach I should follow for this kind of game? The images will be in the screen during the whole lifetime of the game and also there will be simple animations, like picking what card to throw and throwing it.

How to handle this situation and what is a solution that will avoid memory issues during the game in the future?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, it happened because you added too many views in your Linearlayout and made your view-hierarchy thick without any depth.

I think the best approach would be using [RecylerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) for this problem Because RecyclerView has its own way of memory management. You can even curve those cards on screen using custom [LayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager) (Like if they are held on hands).
Two vertical RecyclerViews and two horizontal will do the job.

If by any chance it didn't work, try to wrap those RecyclerViews in [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments).

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising. I will try it out and mark this as answer if it works out as I want it to.

Comment: I forgot to mention: Try to disable three of them that are responsible for showing opponents cards. Because their scroll interception may lead to possible scroll confliction.